# How to raise a case with salesforce from ISV developer org from where we create the managed package?

Tags: customer-community, customer-portal, isv

I am working as a developer for an ISV salesforce partner. We have some issue and we want to raise a case with salesforce for that. The isssue can be reproduced on our partner developer org from where we create our package and I tried creating case from help link in that org but for that it is asking me to login and when I try to login using credentials of my partner developer org it is giving me no user found error.

I need to riase a case with Salesforce support. Can anybody please help me to understand is it possible to raise a ticket with salesforce from partner developer account ? or it is only possible only through partner business org ( the org that has environment hub and used to manage all the other orgs for testing and development purpose). Can anybody explain me what is the procedure for ISVs to raise the ticket with Salesforce Support ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we can raise a case from Partner developer org. I tried in past and didn't get success.
You need the environment hub org to raise the case from there you can share details of this Org.
Also if you don't have premier support salesforce won't help you much in that case.

From partner org > login > go to home > There you find button Support and Case> click on that > select the category > fill the required details. > continue.

Once you raised the case you can see them under your name > My Cases.

Answer (score 1):

Raise it from the partner portal providing the correct org id and granting SF login access. Be very descriptive and detailed in your description of the issue